# avoiding global variables while using GLUT

Tags: c++, scope, glut

GLUT is a great API and it's very easy to use but I am having some difficulty with how it handles scope. When defining callbacks there is no option to pass parameters so it seems to me as though the programmer is forced to rely on global variables, which I find difficult to accept. Right now I have all the GLUT code in it's own module, running on it's own thread, and define a static pointer which I assign at the entry point to the module, like so:

**Main module**

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    int foo;
    boost::thread graphicsThread(glutMain, argc, argv, &foo);

    //...

    graphicsThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**GLUT module**

```
static int* FOO_REF;

int glutMain( int argc, char** argv, int* foo ) {
    FOO_REF = foo;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //etc...
```

Is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using freeglut or a derivative and willing to confine yourself to freeglut derivatives only it has a non-standard extension to solve exactly the problem. You can associate a `void*` with every window. If you make that a struct that contains all the per-window data you want you can avoid the globals entirely.

Synopsis:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>


void * glutGetWindowData();
glutSetWindowData(void *data);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was declare a global.h for all my globals. And initialize them in main. For my "basic/general" variables (ie camera, position, iterationNumber,...) they were all declared seperately. In main:

```
include "global.h"
Vector position_g = ...
Vector angles_g   = ...
int time_g        = 0;

int main () {
    ...
}
```

But for the variables that were "section specific" ie only in one game mode/level, I made a union and an enum.

```
enum mainGame{skipLevel, ...};
enum mainMenu {viewingSettings, ...};

typedef union generic_union {
    int i;
    char c;
    bool b;
    char s[100]; // or char * s;
    float f;
} generic;
```

And declared a globalData variable.

```
extern generic * globalData; // in global.h
generic * globalData = NULL; // in main
```

Which can now be used:

```
int main () {
    ...
    globalData = malloc (sizeof (generic)*numGlobals);
    globalData[skipLevel].b = false;
    ...
}
```

Now when in your key press handling function,  you can assign a key to toggle globalData[skipLevel]. And in any other file all you have to do is include global.h.

```
include "global.h"
void onKeyPress (... ) {
     If (inMainGame) {
         If (key == SPACE) {
             globalData [skipLevel] = true;
          }
    }
```

And finally the use:

```
include "global.h" 
void levelManager () {
     ...
    if (globalData[skipLevel]) level++;
     ...
}
```

**Pros**
    Only have to lug around **1** variable and one include.

You can free variables you no longer want or are using in that instance. (*very* useful for reducing "pollution"). If one game mode only needs 1 variable, thats all you have to store, if it needs 48, just as easy!

Can easily handle any variable type, by adding it to the union.

Totally Portable

**Cons**
   Have to remember variable type to dereference the generic union (not that hard)

And watchout for enums being used (you can use a style for enums like mainMenu_e to solve this)

Adds complexity, but as the variable number grow, a system like this because well worth it.

Personally I find this very neat despite the few extra moving parts.
 If this is unclear let me know, and Ill try to fix it :)